# MVC C# migration Er

Tags: migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am starting a MVC code project.

I created Tables and connection classes and added connection string to websting than enabled migrations but not seenable on VS. here's my pics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNyFa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ54p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BaAd.png)

I also removed re added table created new project and tried on one table. its been 3 hours :) help me

Creating database but not seenable on DB

Comment: also installed EntityFrameWork 6 for both layers(entity &DataAccess)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.